# Recursive conversion to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have a question, I have the following code:

```
$s = 'a/b/c';

$array = array_reverse(explode('/', $s));

$result = [];

foreach($array as $key) {
    $result = [$key => $result];
}

Print_r($result);
```

(demo https://ideone.com/CJMvs0)

From the rows we get the usual one-dimensional array, then from this array we need to recursively create a multidimensional array, using its elements as keys

My code works with a cycle, the question is, can I solve a similar problem without cycles?

Thanks!

Comment: take a look at [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius, can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: What do your mean exactly with `without cycles`? You are using a foreach, do you want to turn that into a recursive function?

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I want to get the same result without using cycles, but using other functions.

Comment: You mean "without `foreach`" ?

Comment: @trincot, without `for`, `foreach`, `while`.

Comment: @wnull nvm, I misunderstood your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive way to do it:

```
function nest($keys) {
    return count($keys) ? [$keys[0] => nest(array_slice($keys, 1))] : [];
}

$array = nest(explode('/', 'a/b/c')); // example
```

`array_slice` will take a copy of the array without the first element. This copy overhead can be avoided by passing an *offset* in the array:

```
function nest($keys, $start = 0) {
    return $start < count($keys) ? [$keys[0] => nest($keys, $start+1)] : [];
}

$array = nest(explode('/', 'a/b/c')); // example
```

Alternatively, more closely to what you had, is by using `array_reduce`:

```
$array = array_reduce(array_reverse(explode('/', $s)), function ($acc, $key) {
    return [$key => $acc];
}, []);
```

It is a pity that PHP does not offer an `array_reduce_right` function like is available in JavaScript, as that would relieve us from having to reverse the array first.

Comment: But isn't that doing array_reverse inside array_reduce is same as doing nested foreach? While OP current solution is only 1 foreach.

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius, I just provided an alternative that did not use `for`, `foreach` nor `while` as OP requested in comments. Obviously the internal interpretation of these constructs involves iteration.